# Assigning different variable names for every group in df.groupby in python using loops

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have patients data that has been grouped on the basis of patient Ids.
Now, I want each group to be stored in a new variable automatically with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dictionary. The keys of the dictionary would be patient’s ID and value of that ID would be the data of that patient. 
To store any new data to dictionary, you can use this format:

```
dict1[‘ID’] = data
```